# Get last part of numbers from string

Tags: android, regex, string

I am trying to get only the **last part** of numbers from a string using `regex` but somehow it only shows me the first part (1.2.54 /1.5 / 1.568).

Any help is appreciated.

Example strings could be:

```
1.2.54 (4587) //should result in 4587

1.5 b458 //should result in 458

1.568 build45 version6 //should result in 45 6
```

My method:

```
private static String getVersionAddition(String str) {
        String version = "";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(([0-9])+(\\.{0,1}([0-9]))*)+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

        if (!m.find()) {
            Log.e("ERROR", str + " skipped");
        } else
            version = m.group();
        Log.e("VERSION", version);

        return version;
    }
```

Comment: The pattern doesn't seem clear. Why result for "1.568 build45 version6" is "45 6" but not "6"? What makes a part of number "last"? There is a non-numeric character before "6" but it's not the last part for some reason that I couldn't understand.

Comment: Hi, to make it more clear I only need the last part(s) of numbers from a string, see my examples please.
So if I have a string as 1.2.54 (4587), I only need the 4587 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Pattern:
`(\d+)(?!.*\d)`

Replace line:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(?!.*\\d)");
```

It Outputs:

```
1.2.54 (4587) -> 4587

1.5 b458 -> 458

1.568 build45 version6 -> 6
```

Comment: Hi Firoz, first of all thx.
I wanna use this function to compare version of apk files, I need to seperate the last part for checking otherwise version 3.5 would be smaller then 3.2 b456, it recognizes 3.2 b456 as a new version which is not.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, I was at work.
Seen that this points me to the right direction, I accept the answer, many thx.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String args[]){
    String str1 = "1.2.54 (4587)";
    String str2 = "1.5 b458";
    String str3 = "1.568 build45 version6";
    str1 = str1.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", " ");
    str2 = str2.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", " ");
    str3 = str3.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", " ");
    System.out.println(str1.trim().substring(str1.trim().lastIndexOf(" ")+1));
    System.out.println(str2.trim().substring(str2.trim().lastIndexOf(" ")+1));
    System.out.println(str3.trim().substring(str3.trim().lastIndexOf(" ")+1));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple ways to do this, although you should be able to get the remaining digits with:

```
^[0-9.\d\s]+[\D]*|([\d]+)
```

Then just reference match group 1 to get the results.

**Example**:

https://regex101.com/r/2TY8Eh/1